# Very silly dialog from old werewolf/vampire/frankenstein movie -- which one?

Tags: story-identification, movie

It may in fact be one in which all 3 monsters are involved. The dialog is something like this: A mad scientist is unhappy with a man and he tells him he plans to replace the man's brain with that of a werewolf so that he will be "tortured every full moon" or something.

Even as a little kid, I thought, "What??"

I suggest that if it was one with all 3 creatures, it was almost certainly (had to be legally?) made by Universal.

Comment: Werewolves, frankenstein and vampires are all rights-free. That's where there's so damn many films about them.

Comment: @Valorum: This was an old one and I recall Universal did have rights. Dracula for sure was not rights-free -- that is why Nosferatu is so-named even though the plot is close to Dracula -- Stoker's widow was still alive and he died in the 1912 -- I don't know what the time period was then but nowadays it is many years after death of author. Wolfman and Frankenstein should be long out of copyright if they ever were covered. Maybe "wolfman: specifically could be a copyrighted but not" werewolf." Of course, "vampire" could not be copyrighted.

Comment: [Monster Mash: 13 Movies Where Frankenstein Meets Dracula Meets The Wolf Man](https://www.monstercomplex.com/blog/monster-mash-13-movies-where-frankenstein-meets-dracula-meets-the-wolfman) - One of these, perhaps?